# React Select inside Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, react-select, semantic-ui-react

I have a simple `React Select` as content prop in a `Semantic UI React Popover` component. I am constrained by each of the package versions inside the project (available in the following codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wy194rz908):

- React: `~15.5.0`
- ReactDOM: `~15.5.0`
- React-Select: `^2.1.1`
- Semantic UI React: `0.71.5`

As you can see, the React Select options closes when a selection is done.

On the other hand, I found that updating React, React-DOM and SemanticUI to their latest versions make the feature work. As you can see, the selection is done and the Select options do not fold (available in the following codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/6y14qyykk3).

As I can not update update the React and SUIR, what workaround should I follow in order to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am controlling the Popup using the `open` prop available through its props api. I change its state from true to false when clicking the caret down icon button.

Solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/rmoxx98qkn

Comment: If you click in the textbox then outside textbox popup closes anyway

Comment: yeah, I still need to fix where to set the onBlur

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `Controlled Popup Component`, as stated in docs:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Popup } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class PopupExampleContextControlled extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  toggle = () => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })

  handleRef = node => this.setState({ node })

  render() {
    const { node, open } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Button content='Open controlled Popup' onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Popup context={node} content='Hello' position='top center' open={open} />
        ---------->
        <strong ref={this.handleRef}>here</strong>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PopupExampleContextControlled
```

In this way you can control when popup opens and closes.